# How to Start Tor in Full Screen

Tags: configuration

This is a very small problem, but annoying.  I can't find an option so that when you open Tor, it comes up full screen rather than at about 90% of the full screen.  I usually just click the full screen icon at the top right of the page, but still...

Any response would be appreciated!  I have a feeling that if I can locate the option for this (if available), it will lead to other options as well.

ANSWER: On Windows, just right-click on Tor browser icon -> Properties -> Run -> Maximized. DONE.

Answer (score 3):

Tor Browser intentionally doesn't start in full screen mode and will resist attempts to make it do so because it harms user anonymity to allow it to happen. I do not expect that there is an easy or supported way to do this.

Since sites can measure screen size, this can be used to split anonymity sets and so Tor opens itself up at a size based on a granular scale to hide the users screensize from the sites they're visiting.

Making Tor Browser in full screen will remove this protection and allow sites to more easily track your Tor Browser between different sessions (and link it to some unchangable aspect of your hardware, I.E. your screensize).

Comment: Thank you so much for your response! I had no idea that screen size could effect tracking! Now that I have that very important piece of information, I am sure I will get used to the slightly smaller size in no time. :)

Comment: Sounds like a pretty solid reason to open at less than full page. You can go to full page right after opening anyhow and it's no big deal compared to the rationale. I learned something and will not ask again. Thank you, HRH Basque Babaan Bouquabono